# 'No cores Created' in Tomcat while using Solr

Tags: tomcat, solr

I'm working on large e-commerce site containing  200k products which is based on ASP.NET MVC3(C#). For better performance of site search feature, I've decided to use Solr Search. I'm new in Solr and Tomcat 7. I've googled and found  [this](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.in/2010/01/full-text-search-using-solr-lucene-and.html) link and followed it.
When replacing schema.xml with existing,I got an error like below

> HTTP Status 500 - Severe errors in solr configuration. Check your log
>   files for more detailed information on what may be wrong. If you want
>   solr to continue after configuration errors, change:
>   false in
>   solr.xml -------------------------------------------------------------
>   org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: No cores were created

What could be the problem?Am i doing wrong something or what?

Comment: Can you please `Check your log files for more detailed information on what may be wrong.` Or at least post them...

Comment: where are logs files of Tomcat?How can i get it?

Comment: In your tomcat installation directory in the folder `logs`. Please do not post the entire log file. Only the relevant error messages.

Comment: there are more than 15 files in logs folder, which one should I look at? I have reviewed all of them but not sure which file is relevant?

Comment: Sort them by date? Also, I think you might want to read [ask]

Comment: I already figured it out... Here it is...http://pastebin.com/Nrr9t0Dv

Comment: And thank you for link on How to Ask...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your log, you can find the following line:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "MA147LL/A"
```

That means, that the application tried to parse the `schema.xml` file and expects a number in the field which contains the String `"MA147LL/A"` at the moment. So search the file for the String and check the documentation to find out, what is wrong with that value.

Comment: The issue was in the elevate.xml file where a wrong entry were created, not sure how.. but cleaning this fixed this error.

Comment: It actually comes from the demo 'elevate.xml' file, shipped with the example solr app, which references document ID "MA147LL/A". So as soon as you switch your id from "string" to a numeric datatype, you will get this error (had the same).

Answer (score 1):

Documentation is your friend:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent

Answer (score 1):

i would like to add,
@Christophe Fondacci is right,
elevate.xml from demo has this value,
just remove the content in the elevate tag, fixed the issue.